# Is there a way to mathematically model the coupling of Quantized EM fields in macroscopic circuits?

Tags: electric-circuits, quantum-electrodynamics, capacitance, inductance

I want to investigate (if it hasn't been done yet, which is very unlikely) how the coupling of a quantized em field couples to a circuit through for example an inductor.
How can one do this? The circuit is a classical element and the field is a quantum element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An LC circuit is basically a single mode of the EM field and can be treated as a harmonic oscillator.  Some example can be found in the [famous paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003491683902026?via%3Dihub) by Caldeira and Leggett.